# Aquamacs overrides my custom-set-faces options

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

I've just installed Aquamacs on my Mac.

I have a .emacs file in my home, which contains all my customizations. Among these, I have:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:stipple nil :background "black" :foreground "grey70" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 140 :width normal :foundry "apple" :family "Monaco"))))
 '(font-lock-builtin-face ((t (:foreground "grey50"))))
 '(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground "darkgreen"))))
 '(font-lock-constant-face ((t (:foreground "grey50"))))
 '(font-lock-doc-face ((t (:foreground "grey50"))))
 '(font-lock-doc-string-face ((t (:foreground "yellow2"))))
 '(font-lock-function-name-face ((t (:foreground "SteelBlue"))))
 '(font-lock-keyword-face ((t (:foreground "red"))))
 '(font-lock-preprocessor-face ((t (:foreground "SteelBlue"))))
 '(font-lock-reference-face ((t (:foreground "LightSkyBlue"))))
 '(font-lock-string-face ((t (:foreground "yellow2"))))
 '(font-lock-type-face ((t (:foreground "violet"))))
 '(font-lock-variable-name-face ((t (:foreground "orange"))))
 '(font-lock-warning-face ((t (:foreground "grey50"))))
 '(isearch ((t (:background "yellow4" :foreground "black"))))
 '(mode-line ((t (:background "grey90" :foreground "black"))))
 '(text-mode-default ((t nil)))
 '(zmacs-region ((t (:background "grey70" :foreground "black")))))
```

This block seems not to be applied automatically.

If I select the lines from the .emacs and manually evaluate them, everything works fine. My guess is that these options are overridden in some other place.

How can I debug this? Where should I set my custom faces?

**UPDATE:**

According to [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PreferencesInAquamacs), preferences should be loaded in the following order:

```
 ~/.emacs  (deprecated -- meaning 'should not be used
 for new installations, but will continue to be supported' -- in Aquamacs on OS X)
 customizations saved by request or automatically by Aquamacs in customizations.el
 /Library/Preferences/Emacs/Preferences.el
 /Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el
 ~/Library/Preferences/Emacs/Preferences.el
 ~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el
```

My `~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el` looks like (by default):

```
 (load "~/.emacs")
```

So this doesn't really make sense to me...

Comment: This is a very old question, but I am having the same problem, where Aquamacs refuses to recognize my custom faces (which are properly placed in `customizations.el`. Does anyone know if this problem was ever addressed?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem setting the color of the point. Then I found the file customizations.el, changed the line setting the colour of the point there, and everything worked fine. I don't know whether your file will be on the same place, but mine was found here:

> /Users/viviannevilar/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/customizations.el

Comment: I tried that already, but it didn't help... :(

Comment: Have you tried asking this question at stackoverflow.com ?? Emacs users tend to "hang out" there more often, and I am sure someone would be able to help you....

Answer (score 3):

All right. This is what I did in the end. Mainly I "imported" the faces into the Aquamacs customizations by doing:

- Started Aquamacs as usual
- Even if the face is defined in the .emacs, it is ignored by Aquamacs
- Opened the .emacs buffered
- Manually selected the face section and evaluated
- Options -> Appearance -> Auto Faces -> Auto Faces (ENABLED)
- Options -> Appearance -> Auto Faces -> Apply Face of some mode -> Text
- Options -> Appearance -> Auto Faces -> Adopt Face and Frame Parameters as Face Default
- Options -> Save Options
- Remove the faces from .emacs

Everything works fine after Aquamacs restart. Groan.

Thanks to anyone here.

Answer (score 2):

In [nick hates software: Aquamacs "Emacs"](http://nick.hates-software.com/2006/07/17/d0894abf.html), Nick found that custom-set-faces worked in Emacs but not in Aquamacs.

As Nick did, you might also try your custom-set-faces code in the Lisp interaction window, being careful as regarding his ^J problem (which is beyond my level of expertise in Lisp).

If you are using a font-name, you can check that Aquamacs understands it by using `emacs -fn fontname`. In case of an error, custom-set-faces just fails and Emacs then goes on using the font it would have used otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The full Emacs startup sequence is documented in the [Startup summary section of the Emacs Lisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html). This manual doesn't document Aquamacs-specific extensions.

In a comment, you mention that doing your customizations from `term-setup-hook' still doesn't work. So what overrides them is either in`window-setup-hook' or in an Aquamacs-specific step.

Aquamacs has some specific customization for faces which may be overriding your customizations done through the standard Emacs mechanism. They can be [turned off](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/AquamacsFAQ#toc21) by including `(aquamacs-autoface-mode 0)` in your `.emacs` or through the menu “Options / Appearance / Auto Faces / Auto Faces”.

The Emacs wiki has some information on [making Aquamacs behave like other Emacsen](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AquamacsEmacsCompatibilitySettings).

Comment: I checked and the autofaces are disabled already. :(

Comment: Also, I added the whole set-faces block. Maybe that can help.

Answer (score 1):

For info about the .emacs file and troubleshooting, see this [emacswiki.org article](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InitFile).

See also this article, [The Init File, ~/.emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html), for possible conflicts.

From [Why doesn't this [terminal or window-system setup] code work in my `.emacs' file, but it works just fine after Emacs starts up](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/emacs-21.1/html_chapter/faq_10.html#SEC135) :

> During startup, Emacs initializes
>   itself according to a given code/file
>   order. If some of the code executed in
>   your `.emacs' file needs to be
>   postponed until the initial terminal
>   or window-system setup code has been
>   executed but is not, then you will
>   experience this problem (this
>   code/file execution order is not
>   enforced after startup).
>
> To postpone the execution of Emacs
>   Lisp code until after terminal or
>   window-system setup, treat the code as
>   a lambda list and set the value of
>   either the term-setup-hook or
>   window-setup-hook variable to this
>   lambda function. For example,
>
> ```
> (add-hook 'term-setup-hook
>           (lambda ()
>            (when (string-match "\\`vt220" (or (getenv "TERM") ""))
>              ;; Make vt220's "Do" key behave like M-x:
>              (global-set-key [do] 'execute-extended-command))))
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this. I updated the question with some comments. Also, I tried to `(add-hook 'term-setup-hook (lambda () MY_OLD_CODE ))` but it didn't help (assuming this was the way it was supposed to be used - I suck at Lisp).

Comment: I'm not much better at Lisp, but somehow I feel that timing is the explanation : the custom-set-faces options are not read at the right time.