# Remap “cmd”+“W” to kill-buffer in Aquamacs?

Tags: aquamacs

In [Aquamacs 3.2](http://aquamacs.org), I want to remap <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> so it will kill the current buffer instead of closing the frame. I use Aquamacs in a classic Emacs style with one window, so I close buffers far more often than I close windows.

I tried this in my `.emacs` to no effect.

```
(global-unset-key [?\s-w])
(define-key global-map [?\s-w] 'kill-buffer)
```

I also tried a variation on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/267469/how-do-i-bind-cmdw-to-kill-the-current-buffer-in-emacs-on-osx) but it still kills the window.

```
(defun kill-current-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
(global-unset-key (kbd "s-w"))
(global-set-key (kbd "s-w") 'kill-current-buffer)
```

I also tried putting that code into `~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el` as [suggested in this answer](https://superuser.com/q/153123/167207).

I've verified with `describe-function` that it is loaded.

```
kill-current-buffer is an interactive Lisp function in `.emacs'.

It is bound to s-W.

(kill-current-buffer)

Not documented.
```

Comment: Have you been able to establish if any preference settings that you might add are being read in?

Comment: @JonathanS Yes, `.emacs` and `~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el` are definitely being read in as I have other preferences in them.  Even if I use `eval-region` on the code it does not work.  I verified with `describe-function` that it is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on.  First, Aquamacs has remapped the Mac OS X command key to <kbd>alt</kbd>.  So it should be `(global-set-key '[(alt w)] 'kill-current-buffer)`.

But that gives a warning because of the second thing, `osx-key-mode` has defined its own `osx-key-mode-map`.  Emacs suggests to redefine that key in that keymap with `define-key`.

```
(defun kill-current-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
(when (boundp 'osx-key-mode-map)
    (define-key osx-key-mode-map '[(alt w)] 'kill-current-buffer))
```

Comment: Great. How did you determine that OS X command key had been remapped to alt?

Comment: @JonathanS I realized the function was being loaded, but the problem might be that my key binding was wrong. In searching for information about key bindings someone mentioned remapping the Command key to Alt. I tried it and it worked.